# How to differentiate different names?

Tags: python

FIGURED IT OUT! IT WASN'T LIKE THE ANSWERS BUT I ADDED A SPACE CHARACTER INTO firstName AND THEN EDITED THE VARIABLE lastName

```
def nameFinder(rollCall, aName):
    spaceCharacter = aName.index(" ")
    firstName = aName[0:spaceCharacter]
    lastName = aName[spaceCharacter:len(aName)+1]
    if (firstName in rollCall) or (lastName in rollCall):
        return True
    else:
        return False



rollCall = "Bobby Lee", "Margaret Me"
print(nameFinder(rollCall, "Bob Ce"))
```

For this function, I have to find whether the first or last name is in the rollCall. It does not have to be both first and last, only first or last. For example "Bob Ce" would result in False because "Bob" was not in the          rollCall. How can I make it like that, since it keeps resulting in True.

Comment: Please reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new problems into the code you are asking people to try and read for you.

Comment: You say **or**. So is the name `'Ce'` in the `rollCall`?

Comment: What's `studentList`?

Comment: I updated my post to also include a modified version of your code too (so you have a better chance of understanding teh algorithm).

Comment: Oops, I meant rollColl @timgeb

Comment: What part of the indentation is wrong? @khelwood

Comment: \@aj2929 The part that **was** wrong was fixed by @timgeb two hours ago.

Comment: Oh okay, I apologize. I didn't check back on the coding when I should have .. @khelwood

Answer (score 1):

After removing `(firstName in studentList) or` from your code, I get `False` as output.

I believe your `firstName in studentList` in your if statement is True, so `True or False` result the output of `True`

Please also note, you are checking `lastName in rollCall` in your `if` statement, in your code `lastName` is `' Ce'`

Answer (score 0):

**Your version, modified**

Basically, we split aName and then loop through rollCall, trying to match all of the names.  If one matches, return **true**.  Otherwise, return **false**.

```
def nameFinder(rollCall, aName):
    studentName = aName.split(" ")
    for name in rollCall:
        rollCallName = name.split(" ")
        if rollCallName[0] == studentName[0] or rollCallName[1] == studentName[1]:
            return True
    return False

rollCall = "Bobby Lee", "Margaret Me"
print(nameFinder(rollCall, "Bob Ce"))
```

**A version that takes up less lines**

The following code will first merge both lists into First, Last, First2, Last2, then will scan against the name entered, and if at least one matches, then it will return true:

```
def nameFinder(rollCall, aName):
    array_merged = [partName for fullname in rollCall for partName in fullname.split(" ")]
    return any([checkingPartName in array_merged for checkingPartName in aName.split(" ")])

rollCall = ["Bobby Lee", "Margaret Me"]
print(nameFinder(rollCall, "Bob Ce"))
```

Note:  Since we are checking if either name exists in the list, I think merging the two lists would simplify the code.  However, if you are only given ["Bobby Lee", "Margaret Me"], then this function will work like a charm.